# App Center Test task: uitest (Xamarin UI Test)

Tags: xamarin.uitest, appcenter

Im experiencing this issue in my post-build script.

This is my result after running my appcenter test command:

appcenter test run uitest --app "ganta4533-gmail.com/AndroidAPP" --devices b660b8e7 --app-path C:\Rajesh\Automation\zyto.maui.prototypes\NavigationComplexData\bin\Debug\net6.0-android\com.companyname.navigationcomplexdata.apk --test-series "master" --locale "en_US" --build-dir C:\Rajesh\Automation\zyto.maui.prototypes\NavigationComplexData\bin\Release\net6.0-android --uitest-tools-dir C:\Users\medur.nuget\packages\xamarin.uitest\3.2.2\tools

Error message:

```
Preparing tests... failed.
Error: Failed to prepare UI Test artifacts using command "test-cloud.exe prepare" with error message:
The app file was not found, please try again. If you can't work out how to fix this issue, please contact support.

Further error details: For help, please send both the reported error above and the following environment information to us by going to https://appcenter.ms/apps and opening a support ticket (using the help menu in the upper right corner of the screen)


    Environment: win32
    App Upload Id: ganta4533-gmail.com/AndroidAPP
    Timestamp: 1667454962180
    Operation: RunUITestsCommand
    Exit Code: 3
    User Email: ganta4533@gmail.com
    User Name: ganta4533-gmail.com
    User Id: 4d2033a6-fbac-4d76-9f4d-ef31b49cf63f
```

This is my result after running my appcenter test command:

appcenter test run uitest --app "ganta4533-gmail.com/AndroidAPP" --devices b660b8e7 --app-path C:\Rajesh\Automation\zyto.maui.prototypes\NavigationComplexData\bin\Debug\net6.0-android\com.companyname.navigationcomplexdata.apk --test-series "master" --locale "en_US" --build-dir C:\Rajesh\Automation\zyto.maui.prototypes\NavigationComplexData\bin\Release\net6.0-android --uitest-tools-dir C:\Users\medur.nuget\packages\xamarin.uitest\3.2.2\tools

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if your issue is related to the one posted here:
https://github.com/microsoft/appcenter/issues/2447#issuecomment-1450227727
the only version of Xamarin.UITest that works with the app center is 3.2.9 and lower